# How to display data api in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

permission to ask, I'm trying to display data into a listview and I've managed to get the data seen from the response console below but the data doesn't appear in the UI, is there something I missed or was there something wrong in my writing.
Thank you.

this is when i do a data API call

```
class ListDosenProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  static Future<List<ModelDosen>> getDosen() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/dosen',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List result = json.decode(response.body);
      return result.map((e) => ModelDosen.fromJson(e)).toList();
      // return ModelDosen.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

and this is when i call it inside the widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../../models/dosen/dosen_model.dart';
import '../../../provider/dosen/dosen_provider.dart';
import '../../../theme.dart';
import '../../../widgets/custom_appbar.dart';

class DosenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DosenPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DosenPage> createState() => _DosenPageState();
}

class _DosenPageState extends State<DosenPage> {
  List<Datum> data = [];

  //  @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   fetchData();
  // }

  // fetchData() async {
  //   final apiResponse = await ListDosenProvider().getDosen() ??;
  //   setState(() {
  //     data = (apiResponse.data!);
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppbar(
          title: 'Dosen',
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<ModelDosen>>(
          future: ListDosenProvider.getDosen(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(8),
                        ),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                            blurRadius: 9,
                            offset: const Offset(
                                1, 2), // changes position of shadow
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  data[index].name.toString(),
                                  style: bold6,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  data[index].prodi.toString(),
                                  style: regular6,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 12,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 94,
                                      height: 32,
                                      child: TextButton(
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              const Color(0xffB3FFAE),
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Email",
                                          style: boldButton1.copyWith(
                                            color: const Color(
                                              0xff379237,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 8,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 94,
                                      height: 32,
                                      child: TextButton(
                                        onPressed: (() {}),
                                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                          backgroundColor:
                                              const Color(0xffC5D5FF),
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: Text(
                                          "Detail",
                                          style: boldButton2.copyWith(
                                            color: primaryColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/user.png',
                              width: 50,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: primaryColor,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the response when calling API the response is also Ok 200

[image]

[image]

Comment: its seems `size` error in your UI. where did you use that `FutureBuilder`  inside `Column` widget?

Comment: yes, i'm use column

Comment: even though I deleted the column but the data still doesn't appear in the widget

Comment: Please put the column and inside use listview with wrap of expaned widget

Comment: Also, you itemCount: should be snapshot.data.length

Comment: @sharon please check above

Comment: still error, even if with snapshot i can't access data in model, can you give an example.

Comment: Please put whole Ui part code so i can help with your code @s

Comment: if (snapshot.hasData) {

List<ModelDosen> datalist = snapshot.data;

print(“list ==>${datalist}”);

Comment: Tell me the whats print into a list into a console

Comment: i've update this questiuon

Comment: @sharon please print the log inside the hasData

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251018/discussion-between-rahulvflutterandroid-and-sharon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace your class with this

```
class ListDosenProvider {
  static Future<List<Datum>> getDosen() async {
    String url =  Constant.baseURL;
    String token =
        await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await https.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/dosen',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
  
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;

      ModelDosen dosen = ModelDosen.fromJson(result);

      List<Datum> l = dosen.data??[];

      return l;
    
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

And update your remove ? from `Datum` model class is

```
 class ModelDosen {
  ModelDosen({
    this.status,
    this.code,
    this.data,
  });
 
  String? status;
  String? code;
  List<Datum>? data;
```

Ui part is

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fabState.setFabStatus = FAB_STATUS.not_visible;
    fabState.setBottomNavStatus = NAV_STATUS.not_visible;
    getData();
  }

  Future<List<Datum>> getData() async {
    final result = await ListDosenProvider.getDosen();
    return result;
  }


 child: FutureBuilder<List<Datum>>(
                future: getData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Container(
                      child: const Text("error"),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                                  spreadRadius: 1,
                                  blurRadius: 9,
                                  offset: const Offset(
                                      1, 2), // changes position of shadow
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        snapshot.data![index].name.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        snapshot.data![index].prodi.toString(),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        height: 12,
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 94,
                                            height: 32,
                                            child: TextButton(
                                              onPressed: () {},
                                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    const Color(0xffB3FFAE),
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              child: const Text(
                                                "Email",
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            width: 8,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 94,
                                            height: 32,
                                            child: TextButton(
                                              onPressed: (() {}),
                                              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    const Color(0xffC5D5FF),
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              child: const Text(
                                                "Detail",
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/user.png',
                                    width: 50,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the `data` variable is assigned from the `snapshot` data if you are using it

```
FutureBuilder<List<ModelDosen>>(
                  future: ListDosenProvider.getDosen(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      
                      /// set the data
                      data = snapshot.data;

                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                             return listTile(data[index]);
                          });
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                       /// Handle error
                    } else {
                      /// Show Progress Indicator
                    },
                   })
```